# Disregard <Enter> keystroke when obtaining user inputs in Python 3.4 (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am taking input from a USB PDF417 scanner - the input comes in as an `@` sign followed by an `<Enter>` keystroke and then a long series of characters with spaces followed by another `<Enter>` keystroke. This long string of characters is what I need. The USB scanner acts as a keyboard.

My issue: a typical call to `input()` or `tkSimpleDialog()` only records the `@` symbol and then closes with the `<Enter>` keystroke.

Additionally, I am running Python 3.4 on Raspbian for Raspberry Pi which does not support the `getch()` feature or `msvcrt.getch()`.

Is there an alternative method of user input that will disregard the `<Enter>` keystroke?

Then I can just close the input method after a specified amount of time (e.g. 1 second of nothing being typed)?

Comment: not really an elegant solution, but use `input()` twice?

Comment: I did originally try this just to see, but if the input were @ <Enter> ABCDEFGH then the result would be that it captures "@" and then maybe "FGH". The response time isn't quick enough, portions are missed

Answer (score 0):

If the number of bytes is consistent, you could use `sys.stdin.read(nBytes)` If you want to attach a timeout to an asynchronous file read, Operating system will start to become important. [This](https://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/) post details how to do it on *nix based systems, and some comments on how to hack it together on windows. The inelegant solution could also be to simply call `input()`, which would work, but could break very easily.